# In mathematics, does a point have a shape?

Tags: geometry

In mathematics, is a [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28geometry%29) a sphere or some other shape? Does a point have a shape?

In physics is there any difference?

Comment: The first question should be on the MathSE. Re the second question, as far as I know physicists and mathematicians treat points in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Define a point as an address in space. Hence a point is of zero width because any continuous region with size greater than zero is defined as a set of multiple points to meet the definition of continuity. This allows a point to distinguish a location from any other regardless of how closely it is inspected. A quoted definition reads ["...[points] do not have volume, area, length..."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry))

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by shape? In mathematics, a point is just a point, and is different from a sphere in almost every setting (i.e. category) I know.